# Java Formatter class, is there an easy way to auto pad columns with spaces?

Tags: java, formatter

Say you have some tabular data where the datas length can vary, is there a provision with the Formatter class to auto adjust the padding?

So instead of this (note column A):

```
columnA    columnB     
1            34.34          
10            34.34
100            34.34          
1000            34.34
```

You get this (note column B):

```
columnA    columnB     
1            34.34          
10           34.34
100          34.34          
1000         34.34
```

Thus far, i've tried this which only simply includes the spaces between %5s     %5s, but they are static and do not adjust to produce the results I want. I was under the impression that the 5 in %5s would auto pad 5 spaces

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
formatter.format("%5s     %5s", columnAdata, columnBdata);
```

Comment: Yes, this functionality is present. A little experimenting and you will be able to easily solve this.

Comment: By the way, what have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely possible.  The way I know off-hand is to configure a minimum width for data in your first column.  To do this you want to make use of the *width* attribute in conjunction with *left-justification* (both documented in [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)).  Here's a start for you:

```
System.out.printf("%-10d %d%n", 1, 100);
System.out.printf("%-10d %d%n", 10, 100);
System.out.printf("%-10d %d%n", 100, 100);
```

This prints:

```
1          100
10         100
100        100
```

The format `%-10d %d%n` can be explained as follows:

```
%-10d: first field

    %: start field
    -: left-justify
   10: output a minimum of 10 characters
    d: format as a decimal integer

%d: second field, using defaults for decimal integer
%n: newline
```